# How to get the SObject type of a field or type reference included in a fieldset?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, fieldsets

I am trying to create a dynamic opportunity line item form in lightning based on product family and name. Hence, I am using the approach of field sets which are storing the list of fields specific to each product. On the UI, when the user selects a family and name, I intend to load the related field set.

However, I also need to retain specific properties of each of these fields to be able to take the right input from the user. This question is about lookup type fields present in these field sets.

From what I can see, the `FieldSetMember` class handles mapping of 5 properties.

1. DBrequired
2. Field Path
3. Label
4. Required
5. Type

For type = reference(lookup), how do I find out which object the lookup is on?